# Z co-ordinate systems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, viewshed

I am running a viewshed 2 analysis and need to add a Z co-ordinate system to my raster terrain data using data management tools/define projection.

Which co-ordinate system should this be for the UK?

Comment: In Great Britain orthometric height is typically referenced to Ordnance Datum Newlyn.

Comment: The vertical coordinate system is part of the SpatialReference for each dataset.